# Attatch multiple values from checkox, with many-to-many relation in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to attatch book and warehouses upon creating a new book in my laravel project.
At the moment i have a checkbox for each warehouse, in my view:

```
@foreach($warehouses as $warehouse)
    <input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="{{ $warehouse->id }}">
        {{ $warehouse->address }}
    <br/>
@endforeach
```

And i have the many to many relations in my book and warehouse models:
Book:

```
class Book extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'books';

    protected $fillable = [
        'ISBN', 'publisher_id', 'author_id', 'year', 'title', 'price',
    ];

    public function warehouses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Warehouse::class);
    }
```

Warehouse:

```
class Warehouse extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'warehouses';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'address', 'phone', 'url',
    ];

    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
    }
```

When submitting the foreach in the form on my book.create view, i try to attach each checked warehouses in the same process as creating the new book:
My Create method:

```
public function create()
{
    $authors = Author::all();
    $selectedAuthor = Book::first()->author_id;

    $publishers = Publisher::all();
    $selectedPublisher = Book::first()->publisher_id;

    $warehouses = Warehouse::all();
    $selectedWarehouse = Book::first()->warehouse_id;

    return view('books.create', compact(['authors', 'publishers', 'warehouses'],
                    ['selectedAuthor', 'selectedPublisher', 'selectedWarehouse']
    ));
}
```

And my store method to store the created data:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'ISBN' => 'required',
        'author_id' => 'required',
        'publisher_id' => 'required',
        'year' => 'required',
        'title' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
    ]);

    try {
        Book::create($request->all());

        $book = Book::first(); // Book::first(); saves to the first found book (id 1), needs to be fixed to the requested book.
        foreach ($request->checked as $value){
            $book->warehouses()->attach([$value]);
        }

        return redirect()->route('books.index')
            ->with('success','Book created successfully.');

    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        var_dump($e->errorInfo);
    }
}
```

The problem is my

```
$book = Book::first();
```

saves to the first found book (id 1, even though i might be creating book id 43), needs to be fixed to the requested book that is currently being created.

Comment: $book = Book::first(); //Get your book something like this
$book->warehouses()->attach([$value]); //You should attach to the book object, not to the request object.

Comment: Thank you, that would be perfect, but in this case, while using first(), the warehouses would be bound to the first book found, which would be id 1.
What would you choose since there is no requested()

Comment: @Xelerate Don't you have a book id in the page you can select the checkboxes? If not, you should pass the `book_id` to that page via the url or put it in a hidden input so you can access it with request.

`<input type="hidden" name="book_id" value="{{ $bookId }}">` Then you can `Book::find($request->book_id)`

Comment: @Dennis I have updated my question.
But yes, it would help to have the book id, the thing is, that i dont set the id myself, thats auto incrementing. And i actually first create the book id upon submitting the post.
So i am not sure that i cant catch it in the same process? this is all when creating a new book, and if i try to do the hidden input field like you suggested, i get unknown variable since i am not setting the id anywhere in the process.

Comment: @Xelerate hm so you first create a book and at the same time you want to add those warehouse id's to that book?  It would help if you put the code of your controller, or where this logic is happening in your question.

Comment: @Dennis Sorry for not posting enough material, i have edited my answer with the create and store methods to show exactly how i do :-)

Comment: @Xelerate no problem, but this is much better! I think you are on the right track, just assign the `$book = Book::create($request->all());`  to the `$book` variable and remove the `Book::first()` and  you're done

Answer (score 2):

I have updated my store method by assigning

```
Book::create($request->all());
```

To my $book variable which solved the problem, my store method now looks like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'ISBN' => 'required',
        'author_id' => 'required',
        'publisher_id' => 'required',
        'year' => 'required',
        'title' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
    ]);

    try {
        $book = Book::create($request->all());

        foreach ($request->checked as $value){
            $book->warehouses()->attach([$value]);
        }

        return redirect()->route('books.index')
            ->with('success','Book created successfully.');

    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        var_dump($e->errorInfo);
    }
}
```

And saves the many-to-many relational data upon storing.

Thank you very much for the help Dennis :-)